# Ajax does not return specific data from php

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

This ajax code posts the variables and displays  `$('#data').html(data);` which is been `eco-ed` in `php`.-which works

```
$.post('login.php',{username:username,password:password},
 function(data)
 {
    $('#data').html(data);
    if (data=='login'){
        alert("sucess");
    }
 });
```

However the problem lies on the next line which does not work:

```
 if (data == 'login') {
     alert("sucess");
 }
```

This code is supposed to show a dialog box if the `data == login`
I have looked through different tutorials and this code is supposed to be working but its doesn't for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: try echoing data to see what is being returned

Comment: with this code it gives the dialog when it says "login", but in your description it should work on "to login". Might that be the oversight?

Comment: Tried it its still not working.

Comment: what is data actually returning? From your code it looks like it should be a string but what is it actually returning? Have you viewed the console for errors?

Comment: try to do "alert(data)" and tell us what it says (or it might already be a revelation to yourself ;) )

Comment: what alert(data) shows? Have you tried to look at response in console?

Comment: Please, post here your PHP code.

Comment: the data returns what is been echoed from php from example if the username and the password match i have put echo"login";

Comment: So if data contains "login" what is your problem then? Comparing two strings cause it's messy now.

Comment: please look at the php code i probably have missed something obvious!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put JSON data Type and use json array as response..

```
$.post('login.php',{username:username,password:password},
 function(data)
 {
    if (data.status=='login'){
        $('#data').html(data.status);
        alert("sucess");
    } else{
        alert('not login');
    }
 }, 'json');
```

And in your PHP

```
<?php
#.. put any code before that response because after it you must put exit. 
# No other data except it must be sent! Else you will break it..
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'login'));
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

data holds the return result of the response of login.php.

In your case it probaly returns html, like `<h1> welcome user x</h1>` (I don't know what your code returns so it is an exampe).

If that is the case, you code should check if that is valid. I suggest using JSON. Your login.php checks the login data. If the login attempt is valid you return login: true; And redirect the user.
When in valid just return the data errors and show them with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, if your response fails you will get proper alert.

```
var jqxhr = $.post("login.php", {username : username, password : password}, function(data) {
  alert("success" + data);
  console.log(data);
},'text')
.done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

else you will get alerted by "succes" and your data.

More information how to use this function you can find on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

To be sure it works. Put in login.php

```
<?php 

echo 'ajax works';
exit;

?>
```

You use old functions that will be removed. Use PDO or other engine. 
Your code is not secure. SQL Injections are possible.